# Error preverifying class

Tags: java-me

I am trying to run a project but I get the following error `Error preverifying class` I am referrencing an external library that enables me to use maps. I dont know where I am going wrong. Someone help!Thanx

Answer (score 1):

See Wireless Toolkit FAQ: http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/FAQ.html

> **I want to use an external library, but when I try to build a MIDlet
>   suite that uses it, I get " Error preverifying class..." messages. Why
>   does this happen?**
>
> If you get this error, you are probably using a class library that was
>   written for Java 2 Platform, Standard Edition (J2SE™ platform). This
>   toolkit supports the development of MIDP applications, which have
>   limited capabilities compared to their J2SE counterparts